# Can't I send 2 messages with different key with message queue with child-parent IPC in C?

Tags: c, parent-child, ipc, message-queue, child-process

Trying to send 2 different integers with 2 different keys in same function. but lower one doesn't actually work and only show -1 value.

Child is sending 2 messages, and parent receives it.

and parent's printf receives it with msgrcv, and should show its pid and cpu_burst value.

Tried compiling with gcc, but child() still skips while(sunstatus) and go direct to printf and returns 0.

This is my code.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include "msg_cm.h"
#include "runq.h"
#include "waitq.h"
#include "cidq.h"

void timer_handler(int signum) {
    int temp = runq[0];
    putwtq(temp);
    rmvrnq();
}

int child(int key, int quant){
    int cpid = getpid();
    srand(cpid);
    int cpu_burst = rand() % 100 + 6;
    int io_burst = rand() % 100 + 1;
    msg_sndr(key, cpid);
    msg_sndr(cpid, cpu_burst);
    int runstatus = 1;
    int onoffchk = 0;
    while(runstatus) {
            if (msg_rcvr(getpid()) > 0) {
                onoffchk = 1 - onoffchk;
            }
            if (onoffchk == 1) {
                cpu_burst = cpu_burst - quant;
            }
        }
    printf("Child process terminated.\n");
    msg_sndr(5678, 3);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int temp = 500000;
    int cnt = 1;
    int pid;
    int quantum = 5;
    int count = 9;
    int comp[10];
    while(temp > 0) {
        msg_rcvr(1234);
        temp = temp -1;
    }
    printf("Parent running: %d\n", getpid());
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0) {
            break;
        }
        else if (pid > 0) {
            printf("Child process : %d created.\n", pid);
        }
        else {
            printf("fork() failed!!!");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    if(pid == 0) {
        child(1234, quantum);
    }
    else {
        int tick = 1;
        int end = 10;
        struct sigaction sigac;
        struct itimerval timer;
        struct itimerval stoptimer;
        sigac.sa_handler = timer_handler;
        sigaction(SIGALRM, &sigac, NULL);
        timer.it_value.tv_sec = quantum;
        timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
        timer.it_interval.tv_sec = quantum;
        timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
        stoptimer.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
        stoptimer.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
        stoptimer.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
        stoptimer.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
        setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL);
        while(end > 1){
            if (msg_rcvr(5678) > 0) {
                end--;
                setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &stoptimer, NULL);
                setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL);
            }
            if (msg_exist(1234) != 2) {
                putrnq(msg_rcvr(1234));
            }
            if (runq[0] == -1) {
                printf("%d\tidle\n",tick);
            }
            else {
                printf("%d\tProcess: %d running...\tCPU burst: %d", tick, runq[0], msg_rcvr(runq[0]));
            }
            tick++;
            sleep(1);
        }
        printf("All childs are terminated.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**msg_cm.h**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

struct msgdata {
    long int msg_type;
    int text;
}message;

int msg_sndr(int key, int num) {
    int msgid;
    struct msgdata message;
    char buf[20];
    msgid = msgget((key_t)key, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    if (msgid == -1) {
        printf("error while creating msg q!!!");
        return -1;
    }

    message.msg_type = 1;
    message.text = num;
    if (msgsnd(msgid, (void *)&message, sizeof(message), 0) == -1) {
        printf("msg not sent!!!");
        return -1;
    }
}

int msg_rcvr(int key) {
    int msgid;
    struct msgdata message;
    long int msg_to_rec = 0;
    msgid = msgget((key_t)key, 0666| IPC_CREAT);
    if (msgrcv(msgid, (void *)&message, sizeof(message), msg_to_rec, 0 | IPC_NOWAIT) > 0) {
        return message.text;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
    msgctl(msgid, IPC_RMID, 0);
}

int msg_exist(int key) {
    int msgid;
    msgid = msgid = msgget((key_t)key, 0666| IPC_CREAT);
    struct msqid_ds buf;
    int rc = msgctl(msgid, IPC_STAT, &buf);
    unsigned int msg = (unsigned int)(buf.msg_qnum);
    rc = msgctl(msgid, IPC_STAT, &buf);
    msg = (uint)(buf.msg_qnum);
    if (msg > 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

**all of *idq.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cburstq[20];
int ccount = 0;

void putidq(int num) {
    cburstq[ccount] = num;
    ccount++;
}

int rmvidq() {
    int tmp = cburstq[0];
    for (int tmpnm = 0; tmpnm < ccount; tmpnm++){
        cburstq[tmpnm] = cburstq[tmpnm + 1];
    }
    ccount--;
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: You're passing in too large a value for the msgsz param when calling msgrcv, which can overwrite part of the stack - the msgsz param should be sizeof(message.text) and not sizeof(message).  Same with your call to msgsnd.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).